# What's missing in my Sign In request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I'm trying to access the endpoints of a website (lighterpack.com, github: https://github.com/galenmaly/lighterpack). To test my ability to do this, I'm trying to make a POST call to the 'signin' function in edit.js (bottom).

I'm using Postman to send the POST request, sending it the object {username: myusername, password: myhashedpasswordandusername}

I'm hashing the object manually right now on my local machine, and copying that out to Postman. I created a JS file with the "crypto-js" dependency, and ran the command that the edit.js file uses, after setting var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js').

This might be the part I messed up, but I can't see where. I

My hashing file code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto-js')
var pass = "mypassword"
var name = "username"
var hash = crypto.SHA3(pass+name)

var hash= hash.toString(crypto.enc.Base64)

console.log(hash)
```

I take what the console logs out, and put that in my Postman object as my password. The thing I don't get is that in the edit.js file, CryptoJS doesn't appear defined anywhere, not that I could see anyway. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Original edit.js function:

```
    $(".signin").on("submit", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        var error = "";
        var username = $(".username", this).val();
        var password = $(".password", this).val();
        if (!password) error = "Please enter a password.";
        if (!username) error = "Please enter a username.";

        if (error) {
            $(".lpError", this).text(error).show();
            return;
        }

        $(".lpError", this).text("").hide();

        username = username.toLowerCase();
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3(password+username);
        hash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/signin",
            data: {username: username, password: hash, },
            method: "POST",
            error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var error = "An error occurred.";
                if (data.responseText) error = data.responseText;
                $(".password", form).val("").focus();
                $(".lpError", form).text(error).show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#signin, #lpModalOverlay").fadeOut("slow", removeBlackout);
                $(".password, .username", form).val("");
                signedIn(data.username);
                library.load(JSON.parse(data.library));
                initWithLibrary();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In your ajax call data after hash has an extra comma.. Take that one out.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. The edit.js code that has the ajax call is not my code, but the websites. This code is the action from the login form on the website.

Answer (score 0):

So someone got me the answer. In github, there is a file public/sha3.js that has the CryptoJS variable, and the app.js file declares that file's info (CryptoJS) as a global variable.

I copied sha3.js, and was able to correctly hash my data and then login. Success!